# Sorted map<CString, CString> possible?

Tags: sorting, stdmap

I have a `std::map<CString,CString`> which I subsequently iterate after it is populated.

Is it possible to sort this map by the key value? The key is a name. So when I iterate the map I would like the names in A-Z order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is standard C++ specific container which already keeps the data sorted based on key. So no need to sort after it has been populated. But yes, in order to better handle the cases of duplicate keys, you should use `std::multimap` since `name` can be duplicated if used as key.

Also, it will be better if you use [CMap Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s897094z.aspx), since mixing standard C++ and windows classes seems bit clumsy.

Comment: I did not realise that a map was already sorted based on key. Thank you. I have been using up until now `CMapStringToString` but this does *not* maintain the values sorted.